# 2 Variable induction on a summation

Tags: analysis, induction

I'm trying to prove this is true: 
$$\sum_{i=1}^{k} 2^{i-1}(k-i) = 2^k-k-1$$

I'm used to doing normal inductions on summations, but this one is a little confusing to me. Basically, because both i and k are present in the equation itself am I supposed to ensure that both i goes to k+1 and and k also goes to k+1? 
Does it matter if you start with inducting on k or i first?

I've tried an induction where I induct on i first:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} = \sum_{i=1}^{k} + 2^{k+1-1}(k-(k+1)) =  2^k-k-1+2^k(-1)=-k-1$$

Obviously this isn't what I want since I want the end goal to look like:

$$2^{k+1}-(k+1)-1 $$

Additionally if anyone knows of any places where I could find example problems of summations using two variables I'd love to know.

Comment: $\,\sum_{i=1}^{k} 2^{i-1}(k-i) = k \cdot \sum_{i=1}^{k} 2^{i-1} - \sum_{i=1}^{k} i \cdot2^{i-1}\,$, so no `summations using two variables`, just the difference of two sums in one variable each. The first one is the sum of a GP.

Comment: I am still a little confused on how you would use induction on this. Where would I use the induction hypothesis in the induction itself?

Comment: For what it's worth, you can also prove it without induction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put
$$
S(k) = \sum\limits_{i\, = \,1}^k {2^{\,i - 1} \left( {k - i} \right)} \quad \quad F(k) = 2^{\,k}  - k - 1
$$
so you shall demonstrate by induction that
$$
S(k) = F(k)
$$

Then clearly the induction is on varying the $k$, while the $i$ is just a parameter internal to $S$.

Now

- the identity is true for $k=1$
  $$
  S(1) = \sum\limits_{i\, = \,1}^1 {2^{\,i - 1} \left( {1 - i} \right)}  = 0 = F(1) = 0
  $$
- if the identity is true for $k$ then it is true for $k+1$, because we have
  $$
  \eqalign{
    & S(k + 1) = \sum\limits_{i\, = \,1}^{k + 1} {2^{\,i - 1} \left( {k + 1 - i} \right)}  =   \cr 
    &  = \sum\limits_{i\, = \,1}^{k + 1} {2^{\,i - 1} \left( {k - i} \right)}  + \sum\limits_{i\, = \,1}^{k + 1} {2^{\,i - 1} }  =   \cr 
    &  = \sum\limits_{i\, = \,1}^k {2^{\,i - 1} \left( {k - i} \right)}  + 2^{\,k} \left( { - 1} \right) + {{1 - 2^{\,k + 1} } \over {1 - 2}} =   \cr 
    &  = S(k) - 2^{\,k}  + 2^{\,k + 1}  - 1 = S(k) + 2^{\,k}  - 1 \cr} 
  $$
  and
  $$
  \eqalign{
    & F(k + 1) = 2^{\,k + 1}  - k - 1 - 1 = 2^{\,k}  + 2^{\,k}  - k - 1 - 1 =   \cr 
    &  = F(k) + 2^{\,k}  - 1 \cr} 
  $$

That's all what needed to give the proof by induction

Answer (score 1):

The $i$ in your formula is an auxiliary variable or index to express the sum with the $\sum$ notation instead of using $\cdots$. Consider another example (so you can then try with yours):
$$\sum_{i=1}^{k}(2i-1)=k^2,\:k\in \mathbb N. \qquad (1)$$
Here $\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}(2i-1)$ is a more compact (and perhaps more formal and precise) notation for the $k$-termed sum
$$(2\cdot \underline1-1)+(2\cdot \underline2-1)+(2\cdot \underline3-1)+\cdots+(2\cdot (\underline{k-1})-1)+(2\cdot \underline k-1).$$
Note that each term is $2i-1$ but in the first one $i$ has been replaced by $1$, then by $2$, and so on until $k$ (these numbers are underlined in the previous equation).

And more important for our discussion: there's no such thing as $i$ in this last equation. It's disappeared, even when the original expression *had such 'variable'*.

But as I've said, that's just an auxiliary symbol. Think that it could even be replaced for something like $\bigcirc$, as in $\sum_{\bigcirc=1}^{k}(2\cdot\bigcirc-1)$.

So now, you can use that 'expanded' expression for your proof by induction. When you feel more comfortable with the $\sum$ sign, you can even work with its properties and avoid the expanded expressions with $\cdots$.

In our case, first note that when $k=1$ we have that $(1)$ becomes
$$\sum_{i=1}^{1}(2i-1)=1^2.\qquad (2)$$
The expression on the right side is obviously equal to $1$. Now, on the left side we have a sum in which the index $i$ varies from $1$ to $1$: that is, there is only one term (no actual sum) which is $2i-1$ but taking $i=1$. So on the left we have $2\cdot 1-1=1$, and so $(2)$ is true.

Then, for the inductive step we need to prove that if $(1)$ holds when $k=h$, that is
$$\sum_{i=1}^{h}(2i-1)=h^2,$$
then it also holds when $k=h+1$, which means
$$\sum_{i=1}^{h+1}(2i-1)=(h+1)^2.$$

Note that I did not replace the $i$'s. The induction happens in the variable that really is a variable to which we can assign the value that we want. We could actually have worked without $\sum$ and say that we want to prove that if 
$$(2\cdot \underline1-1)+(2\cdot \underline2-1))+\cdots+(2\cdot (\underline{h-1})-1)+(2\cdot \underline h-1)=h^2$$
holds, then also
$$(2\cdot \underline1-1)+(2\cdot \underline2-1)+\cdots+(2\cdot (\underline{h-1})-1)+(2\cdot \underline h-1)+(2\cdot (\underline{h+1})-1)=(h+1)^2$$
does.

For a proof of this fact consider that in the last expression the terms on the left from the first one until the next to last one add up to $h^2$ (that's the inductive hypothesis), so
$$(2\cdot 1-1)+(2\cdot 2-1)+\cdots+(2\cdot (h-1)-1)+(2\cdot h-1)+(2\cdot (h+1)-1)=$$$$=h^2+(2\cdot (h+1)-1)=h^2+2h+1=(h+1)^2,$$
and this completes the proof.

The same can be expressed with $\sum$ notation, if we consider that doing the sum with $i$ going from $1$ to $h+1$ is equivalent to do it with $i$ from $1$ to $h$ and then adding the term corresponding to $i=h+1$. Then it would be the same:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{h+1}(2i-1)=\sum_{i=1}^h(2i-1)+(2\cdot (h+1)-1)=h^2 +(2\cdot (h+1)-1)=(h+1)^2.$$